# SAP .Net Connector 3.0 - Get Data from BEx Queries

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-bw, sap-r3

I now have to work on a new project extracting financial data from SAP R/3 into Excel and some other datamart. Our SAP guys says, the best way to get the financial data is from BW using BEx and they build couple queries in BEx and I was able to get the data from excel using OLEDB provider and Pivot table. Now for integration purpose, I need to get the same data from SSIS and/or other .Net application (I only know .Net C#). I downloaded SAP .Net Connector (NCo) 3.0, samples and guides,and did a lot of Google'ng around to find if I can access the BEx queries, and the conclusion is yes. But could not find how.

Appreciate if someone provide pointers on how to access BEx queries data. If this is not a good way to approach this, please guide me on the write way to get the data into a .Net application.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a web service you can enable in your BI system called QueryViewData that accepts a query name + filters in and outputs the results a la this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770716/xslt-turn-2-node-sets-into-rows-and-columns).

Comment: Additionally, I've been doing some research on getting metadata for a query. There's an RFC, RSZ_X_COMPONENT_GET, that can tell you what variables/characteristics exist for a given query. Simply specify the I_COMPID parameter as the technical name of the BEx query in question, and then analyze the dozen or so return variables.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider an automation package like automation anywhere. You can use it to pull data from many sources with a single tool, instead of using many tools to pull data from several sources.
Just google it or let me know if you want more info.
Tom

Comment: Thanks TomV.. that's exactly what I am trying to do.. Use SAP .Net Connector for everything, instead of using different connectivity options. While I understand you work for "Automation Anywhere, Inc.", I could not find a relation between automation and data extraction/Integration. I scanned thru all of your website and closed the the browser at the end while still clue less. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: Hi Bhuvan: Interesting. We have several case studies for data integration. Here is a good page: http://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/datatransfer.htm